# Can you use glVertexAttribPointer to assign a smaller vector to a larger one?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

From section 5.8 of [The OpenGL® ES Shading Language (v1.00, r17) [PDF]](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> The assignment operator stores the value of the rvalue-expression into the l-value and returns an r-value with the type and precision of the lvalue-expression. **The lvalue-expression and rvalue-expression must have the same type. All desired type-conversions must be specified explicitly via a constructor.**

So it sounds like doing something like this would *not* be legal:

```
vec3 my_vec3 = vec3(1, 2, 3);
vec4 my_vec4 = my_vec3;
```

And to make it legal the second line would have to be something like:

```
vec4 my_vec4 = vec4(my_vec3, 1); // add 4th component
```

I assumed that [`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) had similar requirements. That is, if you were assigning to a `vec4` that the `size` parameter would have to be equal to 4.

Then I came across the [GLES20TriangleRenderer sample for Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/GLES20TriangleRenderer.html). Some relevant snippets:

```
attribute vec4 aPosition;

maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
```

So `aPosition` is a `vec4`, but the call to `glVertexAttribPointer` that's used to set it has a `size` of 3. Is this code correct, is `GLES20TriangleRenderer` relying on unspecified behavior, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The size of the attribute data passed to the shader does not have to match the size of the attribute in that shader. You can pass 2 values (from `glVertexAttribPointer`) to an attribute defined as a `vec4`; the leftover two values are zero, except for the W component which is 1. And similarly, you can pass 4 values to a `vec2` attribute; the extra values are discarded.

So you can mix and match vertex attributes with uploaded values all you want.

Comment: Interesting. Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves: It's documented in the OpenGL ES specification.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more specific. :-)  For the record, this seems to be documented in section 2.8 of the spec, "Vertex Arrays", under the heading "Transferring Array Elements".